# IIS wont run bat file (UAC Virtualization problem)

Tags: windows, batch-file, iis, uac

IIS hosts a .Net Core that simply needs to run a bat file. The file is part of the project.

On the local machine, everything works properly, but on the server, the bat file is not triggered because it is blocked by UAC virtualization.
On the server, the double-click script runs smoothly, but cannot be started automatically by .NetCore

> .Net core has admin rights to execute the script, also AppPool has the
> rights to execute the script. But the script simply stays blocked by
> UAC.

I tried to completely disable UAC and restarted the server but again the same.

I tried to create a shortcut with admin rights that will run the script but without success.

[image]

Comment: What made you believe that the issue happens "because it is blocked by UAC virtualization"? What exactly is inside this batch file?

Comment: Users will still need to provide administrator credentials to do the installation. When an executable has a requested execution level manifest, Windows automatically disables UAC virtualization.

Comment: @Lex Li - In file is written  - echo test \n pause -
No matter what is written in the file the bat will not start, it looks like the file is blocked by the UAT.

Comment: When you wrote `pause`, you generated a bunch of `cmd.exe` which were pending there and never could finish (so what did you expect to happen?). "No matter what is written in the file" also makes no sense. If your batch file tries to write to a log file and has no improper statements like `pause`, it should be executed successfully. "Not allowed" for "UAC virtualization" showing in Task Manager is for something else, irrelevant to the core problem.